Problem defining payment method id as debit_card in Mercado Pago SDK
Today I generate the card token in my frontend, I make a post to the backend so that the card is associated with the customer and I save some information to list that payment method in future purchases, so I need to say if the card will be debit or credit, this is my current code and it gives an error in the payment method id if I remove it, it passes, if I put debit_card or credit_card it gives an error
public CreateCustomerCardGatewayResponse createCustomerCard(
        String customerId,
        String cardToken,
        String cardIssuer,
        String paymentMethodType
) {
    CustomerCardIssuer aIssuer = CustomerCardIssuer.builder()
            .id(cardIssuer)
            .build();

    CustomerCardCreateRequest aCardRequest = CustomerCardCreateRequest.builder()
            .token(cardToken)
            .issuer(aIssuer)
            .paymentMethodId(paymentMethodType)
            .build();

    log.debug("Creating customer card request object: {}", aCardRequest);

    try {
        log.debug("Creating customer card in Mercado Pago with customer id: {}", customerId);
        final var aCard = customerCardClient.create(customerId, aCardRequest, this.getMPRequestOptions(null));
        log.info("Customer card created in Mercado Pago card id: {} with customer id: {}", aCard.getId(), customerId);
        return new CreateCustomerCardGatewayResponse(
                aCard.getId(),
                aCard.getLastFourDigits(),
                aCard.getExpirationMonth(),
                aCard.getExpirationYear(),
                aCard.getPaymentMethod().getThumbnail(),
                aCard.getPaymentMethod().getName()
        );
    } catch (MPException e) {
        throw new PaymentGatewayException("Unexpected exception on create customer card in Mercado Pago", e);
    } catch (MPApiException e) {
        throw new PaymentGatewayException("API error while create customer card in Mercado Pago", e);
    }
}

